# Enabling Mysql safe updates

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqld-safe

I'm using mysql 5.5 and trying to enable Mysql safe update on my.cnf file

[mysq]
--i-am-a-dummy
-safe-update

it got reflected on root mysql login.

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates'  is ON

But When I tried to use mysql user, the -safe-update is not working and also

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates' show it is OFF.

How to enable mysql safe update for all users permanently?

Comment: Did that user re-login?  Most settings do not affect existing connections.